# Facebook share button is sharing my login page instead of current page URL, title, etc

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, facebook-social-plugins

I have added facebook share button to my webpage using this code:

`<a name='fb_share' border="0">Share</a>`
`<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'>
</script>
<script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'>
</script>`

The above code shares the current webpage properly but when I included a session check at the start of the webpage where I redirect the user to the login page if valid session doesn't exist the above code always shares the login page instead of the current page. I am using PHP header function for redirect. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

To share content from not publicly accessible page use [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Answer (score 0):

i use {}  you can uncomment features as needed.  Keep in mind all share button features where deprecated for the like / recommend button.

---

```
<div id="msg"></div>
    <script> 
            function feedthis() {
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
    //to: ''+tobe+''
        //link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        //picture: ''+pic+'',
        // name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        //caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        //description: ''+msg+''
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }
</script>
```