# Facebook shows my login page on the share dialog instead of the current page title and url

Tags: php, html, facebook, codeigniter

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook share feature in my application but whenever I click on the share button , Facebook will pull up meta data from the head and instead of showing the current title and URL it returns my login page URL and login page title , I have tried this

[Facebook share button is sharing my login page instead of current page URL, title, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853887/facebook-share-button-is-sharing-my-login-page-instead-of-current-page-url-titl)

But according to Facebook the [Feed button was dereciated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.1) and replaced with the share button

The code below is included in every page of my app

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Type of content"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo current_url() ; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My site name"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description ; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Yes I have tried that and still pulls my login page ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think it's got to do something with the Facebook scraper. As mentioned in the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#scraperinfo)

> In some cases you may want to serve a different version of a page to
>   our scraper (containing more Open Graph metadata) than you do to
>   people who are viewing the page. In this case you can target the
>   browser agent used by the scraper:
>
> "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

So I think in the php file of your website you can put in a check for the scraper like this:

```
    if (strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit') {
       // Show more open graph metadata here
    } else {
       // Your login page
    }
```

To make the scraper cache your data, use the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: I have tried included your code in the header , but still shows my login page

Comment: How do you redirect users to your login page? You check their credentials in php?

Comment: yes I do check them with php .. users don't get to see contents unless they are logged in first ..

Comment: So basically, facebook scraper since does not match your credential checker, it received the login page. So in your credential checker, if the user agent is that of facebook's scraper, allow it to see some contents.